# Nodejs webpack and express server together

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, socket.io, phaser-framework

I am developing a browser game using nodejs and phaser framework and I really like this sandbox for the start: https://github.com/nkholski/phaser3-es6-webpack

The thing is, I need to use socket.io, but since I am kind of new to nodejs and these stuff, I jus can't manage to create a server and run it with this webpack at the same time.

I have made a server.js and  pointed package.json for it as a start action.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("listening");
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {...});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js')
    ],
    vendor: ['phaser']
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    definePlugin,
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor'/* chunkName= */, filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'/* filename= */}),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: process.env.IP || 'localhost',
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['./', './build']
      }
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: ['babel-loader'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'src') },
      { test: /phaser-split\.js$/, use: ['expose-loader?Phaser'] }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'phaser': phaser
    }
  }
}
```

So what happened was, that I just created empty listening server and on the other port there was running the webpack project.

Is there any way to make this work together?
Thanks

Comment: did you get it to work?